# How to hide/close all forms and show login when logging out a user?

Tags: c#, winforms

I cannot figure out how to close all open forms and open the login form when the user has left the application idle for a period of time.

The below code almost works but the non-login form(s) are still visible and clickable in the taskbar.

What am I missing here? Also is there something else I should initially be setting `var frm` to?

```
    public static void Logout()
    {
        var frm = Form.ActiveForm;
        for (int ix = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; ix >= 0; --ix)
        {
            frm = Application.OpenForms[ix];
            if (frm.GetType() != typeof(Login))
            {
                logoutIdleUser = true;
            }
        }

        if (logoutIdleUser)
        {
            // Logout user
            MessageBox.Show("You will be logged out.", "Session Expired!");
            frm.Hide();
            new Login().Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are hiding not all forms, but only active. Try to move frm.Hide() to for(...) loop

Comment: Yes that works but I would like to have the last form still visible underneath the messagebox, until the OK button is clicked on the messagebox. Sorry I should have put this in the question.

Comment: Then, add this to the loop: if (Form.ActiveForm != frm) frm.Hide()

Comment: ActiveForm is null. I think because the code is in Program.cs

Comment: Show that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the implementation I have gone with. It shows the messagebox on top of the login form, as opposed to the previous form.
It is not exactly what I was looking for in the question but it is acceptable for the project. Thanks to @CDove for the help.

```
    public static void Logout()
    {
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm.GetType() != typeof(Login))
            {
                frm.Hide();
                logoutIdleUser = true;
            }
        }

        if (logoutIdleUser)
        {
            new Login().Show();
            MessageBox.Show("You will be logged out.", "Session Expired!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can move the hiding call until after the login box shows.  Just shift the order of operations.  Show the logout warning, and make it return the boolean value.  If it's true, hide all of the forms instead of using the type condition

Answer (score 0):

Your close operation isn't coupled with your search for open forms, so you're only closing one form. By changing your `for` loop to contain your close events, you resolve that problem.  Also, I changed to a `foreach` since we're using `frm` as a variable anyway, to make it more readable.  Instead of checking the active form, we use it as the loop variable and declare it there.

```
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
    {            
        if (frm.GetType() != typeof(Login))
        {                               
             frm.Hide();                
        }
        new Login().Show();
        MessageBox.Show("You will be logged out.", "Session Expired!");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you but I get the compile error **'object' does not contain a definition for 'Hide' and no extension method 'Hide' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found**

Comment: That's very strange, since `Application.OpenForms` returns the `FormCollection` which should only contain objects which inherit from `Form`.   Try it with the above edit to explicitly state `frm` is a `Form`.

Comment: The updated answer gives this error **Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.** I think because the collection has changed as the newly displayed Login form gets added to the collection.